# Trimming service area polygons in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: network-analyst, arcgis-pro, service-area

Does anyone know how to trim polygons for a service area network analysis in ArcGIS Pro?

It seems to have a default of 100 meters and I would like to not trim them.

I can't use ArcMap, which easily allows for this. Unfortunately it keeps crashing with the complexity of the network I'm trying to run.

Comment: Looking at the [help file](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/service-area-analysis-layer.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_19BE5BED81E742529E723827CEDBA4DE) it appears that is not an option in Pro. Suggest you add it as an idea over on the geonet website.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think that comment with very slight expansion is worthy of being an answer.